# Some coding on 'Multiline Radiogroup' (Designed by Gavras) needs updating

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, maven, gradle, jitpack

I'm trying to create a multiline radio-group as the number of options I need to show, necessitate this. (His method appears to be the only published method). It seems that since publishing, Android Studio have re-configured some of the 'gradle' settings.

I'm not experienced enough to know where these settings may have migrated to.

I'm trying to place the:

allprojects {
repositories {
...
maven {
url "https://jitpack.io"
}
...
}
}

In the 'build.gradle' (project file). Trouble is, the file doesn't look anything like the example I found on the...

'How to create multiple line radio group in android studio.'
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sw85PqvjrxU&t=3s

...video. It no longer looks like the example in the video.

I tried placing it there but it immediately crashed.

I'm guessing it should go in the 'settings.gradle' file but I don't know if that will cause more problems. Plus, I'm not sure (if it does now go here), whether the code also needs to be modified.